# Is it possible to trigger programmatically on website opened via phone?

Tags: javascript, touch-event

I need to trigger swipe programmatically like on below gif example

[image: Desired behaviour]

I looked in chrome devtools and this swipe calls 3 events: touchstart, touchmove, touchend so probably I need somehow trigger these 3 events to reach such result. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps animating `scrollTop` is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to smoothly scroll the page, you can use [element.scroll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll) and set top to how many pixels from the top you want it to scroll by.

```
element.scroll({ top: 100, behavior: "smooth" });
```

Comment: that could be a solution, thanks